# Show that $\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

> Given a sequence $\{x_n\}, \ n\in\Bbb N$:
> $$
> x_n = \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}
> $$
> Show that $x_n$ converges.

I'm wondering why I'm getting a seemingly wrong result (assuming the problem statement asks to prove convergence):
$$
\begin{align}
x_n &= \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} \\ 
&= \frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n-2)\cdot(2n)}{3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots (2n-1)\cdot(2n+1) } \\
&= \frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n-2)\cdot(2n)}{3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots (2n-1)\cdot(2n+1)} \cdot \frac{2^n\cdot n!}{2^n\cdot n!} \\
&= \frac{4^n (n!)^2}{(2n+1)!} \\ 
&= \frac{4^n (n!)^2}{(2n+1)\cdot (2n)!} \\
&=\frac{4^n}{2n+1}\cdot \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}
\end{align}
$$

By Binomial coefficients:
$$
{2n\choose n} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!(2n-n)!} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} 
$$

Thus:
$$
x_n = \frac{4^n}{2n+1}\cdot \frac{1}{{2n \choose n}}
$$

Doesn't $\frac{4^n}{2n+1}$ grow faster than $\frac{1}{2n\choose n}$ is declining? Shouldn't $x_n$ diverge in that case?

Comment: By the way, Stirling's approximation gives, for $n\to\infty$, $$\binom{2n}n=(1+o(1)) \frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}} 4^n,$$ so actually $$x_n = \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2n+1} (1+o(1))=\Theta(n^{-1/2})\to 0$$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have

$$0\leq x_{n+1} = x_n \cdot \frac{2n+2}{2n+3} \leq x_n$$
thus, your sequence is monotone decreasing and bounded from below and therefore convergent.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Stirling approximation for factorials we can observe the following: $n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n$. This means that, while being a bit sloppy with the $\sim$

$
\begin{align*}
x_n &= \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} \\
 &= \frac{4^n (n!)^2}{(2n+1) (2n)!}\\
& \sim \frac{4^n 2 \pi n \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^{2n}}{ (2n+1) 2\sqrt{\pi n} \left(\frac{2n}{e} \right)^{2n}}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2 n + 1} \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
$

So $x_n \rightarrow 0$